# Sort Tags by date

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress theme. Here is the code I am using there to show the tags in Blog page:

```
<div class="custom-category">
    <?php
      $post_tags_show_text = __('Tags', 'directory');

      $categories_list = get_the_term_list ( $cs_post_id, 'directory-tag', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' );

      if ( isset($categories_list) ){ ?>
        <div class="cs-tags"> <!-- cs Tages Start -->
          <h5><?php echo esc_attr($post_tags_show_text);?></h5>
          <ul> <?php printf( __( '%1$s', 'directory'),$categories_list ); ?></ul>
        </div>
    <?php
     } ?>
    </div>
```

But it is automatically sorts itself alphabetically. Anyway to adjust that so that it will sort by date published/modified?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sort(array,sortingtype);?

Comment: You need to define it somewhere. It will look something like this 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div class="custom-category">
    <?php
      $post_tags_show_text = __('Tags', 'directory');

      $terms = wp_get_post_terms ( $cs_post_id, 'directory-tag', array('orderby' => 'date') );

      if ( isset($terms) ){ ?>
        <div class="cs-tags"> <!-- cs Tages Start -->
          <h5><?php echo esc_attr($post_tags_show_text);?></h5>
          <ul>
          <?php
          foreach($terms as $term) {
              echo "<li><a href='".get_term_link($term)."' title='".$term->name."'>".$term->name."</a></li>";
          }
          ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <?php
     } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-sort-order-with-custom-post-types-and-based-on-custom-field

You need to define it somewhere. It will look something like this

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
'order' => 'ASC');
```

See the link above